# Service worker cache storage not updated when code changes

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

My single page web application, is written as PWA. It's a ASP.NET Web API application, which is hosted under IIS. My application uses a service worker, which precaches my application shell. Other content is written to indexedDB or updated in the service worker cache on-the-fly, as the user clicks through the application.

I have a problem with code changes. When I update code, and refresh my browser, I can see my changes directly in the javascript and html code. When I go offline, my application falls back on the code, which is in my service worker. This code is still old code. It seems not to be updated, when i reload my application. My service worker looks like this:

```
const urlsToCache = ['.' 
    , 'index.html'
    , 'favicon.ico'
    , 'service-worker.js'
    // More sources are cached here
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {

    console.log('\'Install\' event triggered.');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
            console.log('Application shell and content has been cached.')
            return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        }).then(function (event) {
            return self.skipWaiting();
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('\'Activate\' event triggered.');
    return self.clients.claim();
});
```

For registering the service worker, my code looks like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')
                .then(function (registration) {
                    console.log('Registered: ', registration);
                    registration.update();
                    console.log('Updated: ', registration);
                    resolve(registration);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Registration failed: ', error);
                    reject(error);
                });
```

So when the service worker get registered, it also checks for updates. However, it only updates when the service worker code itself is changed. Not when code within my application shell is changed without changing the service worker code itself.

How can i make sure that the code in my service worker is reloaded when I change my application code and refresh my page?

Comment: Check this to update SW https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update

Comment: Hi @Zydnar, thanks for your response. It does something, but still not what i want to achieve. If i update the service worker code, it will update the cache storage. What i want to achieve, is that it updates the cache storage, when only my application shell is changed, so without changing the service worker code itself. I updated the main thread with your additions.

Comment: So you have to update the cache on message send to SW. So let's say changing the shell in callback posts message to SW and then if message === 'updateCache' you do your logic see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage for reference.

Comment: Hi @Zydnar, the problem remains in that case... I can't refresh the service worker cache without changing the serivce worker code itself. The registration.Update() only refreshes the service worker cache, when the service worker code itself has changed. What i want to achieve is to refresh the service worker cache on page refresh (F5 or ctrl+F5)

Comment: What do you call service worker cache? Because to cache you have access even without SW. Besides what do you need cache for if you update the cache in every reload?!

Comment: In my example above, I want to cache everything which is in my urlsToCache array. When I use my browser and open my web application, I can see this is working: files are cached in my service worker cache (I can seen in Chrome DevTools). Now, I make changes to one of these files f.e. index.html. I deploy this change to the web server. On my client i press Ctrl+F5. My application is refreshed, and the change is visible. However, in my service worker cache storage, the old version is there. So when going offline it falls back to the old code before it was changed.

Comment: All you have to do is on refresh change cache name and remove old caches (with different names) - usually cache have name like `v1` and next versions `v2...vn`. see: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#removing_outdated_caches